# how to perform a functional test on a triangle

Tags: java, code-coverage, functional-testing

I am trying to do functional testing to check a triangle. i have three int input. The three input variables each describe the lengths of each side of a triangle. The lengths of the sides of the triangle should be less than or equal to 1000. The output of this method will be one of 5 possible values: 1 for a scalene triangle, 2 for a isosceles triangle, 3 for an equilateral triangle, 4 for values that do not describe a triangle, and 5 for values that are out of bounds.

this is the first test that I wrote, but I have no idea if its correct or not.

```
public class TriangleTypeFunctionalTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testTriangleScalene(x,y,z) {
        if(x < 1000 and y <1000 and z< 1000){
            if ( ( x != y ) and ( x != z ) and ( y !=z ) )  
                return True;
            else
                return False;
        }
        else
            return False;

    }

}
```

I need some help understanding and how to do this

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to know the conditions for three numbers being the sides of a triangle.  They are:

```
// Sides a, b, c
a + b > c
b + c > a
c + a > b
a > 0
b > 0
c > 0
```

Next, you need a way to distinguish between the different types of triangles.  Numerical codes are not the way to go.

```
enum TriangleType {
    EQUILATERAL,
    ISOSCELES,
    SCALENE,
    INVALID,
    OVERSIZE
}
```

Next, you want to write a class that tests three values for being sides of a triangle.  In fact, make it `Triangle` itself, but hold off on writing the type method, as you want to do Test-Driven Development.

```
public class Triangle {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    public Triangle(int a, int b, int c) {...}
    public TriangleType type() {
        return null;
        // Not really written yet.
    }
}
```

Now, you want to write tests for `type()`  You then edit`type()` until your tests succeed.  Let's start with the sides being positive.

```
public class TypeTest {
    @Test
    public void negativeSideAFails() {
        Triangle t = new Triangle(-10, 10, 20);
        Assert.assertEquals(TriangleType.INVALID, t.type());
    }
}
```

You should write similar tests for side b and c too.  The assertEquals method will throw an exception if the two values are unequal, which the JUnit test runner translates into a test failure.

Edit your `type` method until these work, and then continue with tests for the other conditions:

```
    @Test
    public void sideAMustBeShorterThanSumOfOtherTwo() {
        Triangle t = new Triangle(100, 10, 20);
        Assert.assertEquals(TriangleType.INVALID, t.type());
    }
```

Then, write tests for values representing all of the `TriangleTypes`.

You'll have a lot of tests, but you can simplify them later when you learn about `@Parameterized` tests.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. One thing I forgot to mention was that the triangleType class is given to me.

Comment: If it's given to you, use it.  But an enum is fsr better than numerical codes.  At least, use symbolic names and write in `Triangle`: `public static int EQUILATERAL = 3;`  Then just use `Triangle.EQUILATERAL` in your code.  In practice you will someday need to look back on code you wrote six months ago, and you don't want to be in a position to say "What was I doing?"

Answer (score 0):

For you to have a triangle, the lenght of one side has to be lower than the sum of the other two sides

try:

```
if(x+y<z) //not a triangle
if(x+z<y) //not a triangle
```

...

It's been a while since I've studied math, but that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a triangle, each of the sides should be lower than the sum of the other two sides. (I suggest you're using JUnit4).
You have to just pass the conditions for the `(x, y, z)` trey to the `assertTrue` method.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TriangleTypeFunctionalTest {
   private int x;
   private int y;
   private int z;

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
       x = //some mock value;
       y = //some mock value;
       z = //some mock value;
   }

   @Test
   public void testTriangleScalene() {
       assertTrue((x < 1000 && y <1000 && z< 1000));
       assertTrue(( x + y > z) && (x + z > y) && (y + z > x));
   }
}
```

Comment: Since he is trying to write a JUnit test, he should be using assert methods, and the method should be `void`.

Comment: He should be trying to test some sort of triangle object though, not just throwing random numbers in.

Comment: When you say some mock value do you mean just like integers. like x = to some number?

Comment: Yes. You can switch the `integer` type with any other numeric type. :)